# Indian transit visa for Filipino citizen

Tags: visas, india, layovers, filipino-citizens

Philippine National travelling from Abu Dhabi (Residence Visa in Abu Dhabi) to Thailand via India.

I have 2 connections in India with long stop overs during which I want to explore the surroundings (go outside the airport for several hours).

How much is the transit Visa, and is this even valid for my requirement?

Can Egyptian citizens also apply for that same transit visa?

Answer (score 1):

Through the link below you will find that you (and Egyptians) need to apply for a regular visa: http://cibtvisas.nl/ (which is available in English).

The link below, however, states that you can apply for a transit visa: http://in.vfsglobal.co.uk/Transit.html

Either way, you need to apply for a visa well in advance.